# Using ELSEIF Logic with SuccessfullyPostForm

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a CloudPage with 2 URLs that contain unique SuccessfullyPostForm Values. My AMPscript works and I am able to publish the CloudPage UNTIL I try and add in the IF/ElSE Logic to handle the different command statements.

Here is the AMPscript that is causing the error:

```ampscript
IF @SuccessfullyPostForm == "1@YZKWERISRZKSRU^+7$@or$1k&ra5(ue#iaWILERUWEILR" THEN
  SET @Unsub = "marketing_unsub__c"
ELSEIF @SuccessfullyPostForm == "RMM^+7$@or$1k&ra5(ue#iaAJSFKLSAFUIEAOWRUWEA"
  SET @Unsub = "reminders_unsub__c"
ENDIF
```

Am I not able to do this type of logic with a form submit? For context, a sample of the CTA form submit code looks like this:

```html
<div class="cta-wrapper %%=v(@hidden)=%%">
  <form id="marketing-reminders-form" class="mobile-center" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="SuccessfullyPostForm" value="1@YZKWERISRZKSRU^+7$@or$1k&ra5(ue#iaWILERUWEILR" />
    <a class="cta" onClick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('marketing-reminders-form').submit();">Unsubscribe from Marketing & Reminders</a>         
  </form>
</div>
```

If my Ampscript simply states:

```ampscript
IF @SuccessfullyPostForm == "1@YZKWERISRZKSRU^+7$@or$1k&ra5(ue#iaWILERUWEILR" THEN
SET @Unsub = "marketing_unsub__c"
```

Then the CloudPage Publishes and does what I intend. It's only when I add in the ELSE logic that the page does not publish.

Comment: You forgot the THEN at the end of the ELSEIF

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington, unfortunately adding in the 'THEN' statement still did not allow me to publish the CloudPage